# POSTGRESQL Time1 = Time2 and values 2 from time2 + 1 hour interval

Tags: postgresql

Hy Coders, i got a question.
i have a table1 with 2 colums (timestamp,value1) and 3 rows. A table 2 with 2 columes( timestamp, value2) with 1000 rows

Table1 are LAb values from samples Table2 are values from an online measurement with 3min interval.

i want to mean all values2 from table 2 in an interval from timestamp1 = timestamp2 + 1 hour before

has anyone an idea?
[image: sample table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition like:

```
t2.timestamp BETWEEN t1.timestamp - '1 hour'::interval AND t1.timestamp
```

This condition can be used to `JOIN` the tables like:

```
SELECT *   -- the columns you need
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.timestamp BETWEEN t1.timestamp - '1 hour'::interval AND t1.timestamp
```

To get the average of values from table2, you can turn on aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.value, AVG(t2.value) avg_value2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.timestamp BETWEEN t1.timestamp - '1 hour'::interval AND t1.timestamp
GROUP BY t1.timestamp, t1.value
```

Comment: it works! thx! an idea how to use the average on the values 1 from table 2 in this interval?

Comment: @Sascha: you can use aggregation. I updated my answer.